# How to add a marker manually or with draw plugin (folium - Python) and be able to export it or save it?

Tags: python, draw, marker, folium

Draw plugin can save a geoJson file with the objects put on the map. But if I add a marker programmatically or the map already has markers, I lose them, they are not included when draw plugin exports the data into the GeoJson file.

On the other hand, avoiding draw plugin, I made markers with 'ClickForMarker' on an existing map w/markers and then saved the map, but I lose the new markers; they are not present in the HTML, just the original ones (programmatically generated).

Finally, the idea is to find a way to, having a base map with markers, add some new ones, and save (or export) the whole thing.

```
from folium.plugins import Draw

m = folium.Map(location=[52.1, 5.1], zoom_start=12) 

draw.add_to(m)
draw = Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='data.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': {'allowIntersection': False}},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}}
) 

folium.Marker((52.0, 5.0), tooltip='both', icon=icon_red).add_to(m) 
    
m
```

Comment: I don't have a folium recipe to hand, but this demonstrates something similar with ipyleaflet: https://blog.ouseful.info/2019/04/02/fragment-components-for-rolling-your-own-gis-inside-jupyter-notebooks/